# How to upgrade from SSL3.0 to TLS 1.0

Tags: tls

I have a website using SSL V3 and since SSL V3 is vulnerable and dead, we want to upgrade our website to use TLS 1.0. Our hosting server is using windows server 2003 R2. Can someone clarify the following point:

1. Is there something called SSL certificate and TLS certificate or the same certificate can be used for both of them.
2. What are the needed steps to upgrade my website to use TLS instead of SSL.

Comment: Answers to both of these questions are a simple search away. What have you researched on your own so far?

Comment: I have researched "how to migrate iis 6 from ssl to tls"
"is there a need to upgrade certificate to migrate from ssl to tls"
and i couldn't find an article or a document about this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade your operating system (or set up a completely new server with a fresh operating system). The necessary libraries for TLS-1 come with the operating system and are upgraded as long as microsoft provides updates for your OS.

You can re-use the certificate. The problem in your case are the outdated ssl-libraries of the OS.